# GCP App Engine deploy and using a Google Cloud Storage Client Library

Tags: google-app-engine

I installed the Cloud Storage Client Library in my local machine with composer.

My App Engine app uses [StorageClient](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.68.0/storage/storageclient), like the sample code below, to write a file to a Cloud Storage Bucket.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient();

$bucket = $storage->bucket('my_bucket');

// Upload a file to the bucket.
$bucket->upload(
    fopen('/data/file.txt', 'r')
);
```

Are the libraries being copied to the respective App Engine instance when I deploy this app?

Was the authentication process/service account for copying the libraries down to my machine?

Is there a separate charge for using the libraries?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question: "Was the authentication process/service account for copying the libraries down to my machine?" I can't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are the libraries being copied to the respective App Engine instance when I deploy this app?**

In a way they’re copied to the respective App Engine instance but not from your local machine.

This happens during the build stage of the deploy process and you can confirm it by [viewing the build results](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results). You can do that using the Google Cloud console or the Google Cloud SDK.

Here’s an example to view the build logs from the last deployment.

`gcloud builds log $(gcloud builds list --format json | jq -r ".[0].id")`

You can use it in Google Cloud Shell and also pipe it to grep like this:

`gcloud builds log $(gcloud builds list --format json | jq -r ".[0].id") | grep composer`

**Is there a separate charge for using the libraries?**

As explained in the documentation for [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing), depending if you’re using the Environment [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/) or [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/), the billing rates differ.

With Standard Environment you choose an instance class and you’re billed [per hour per instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing) accordingly while with Flexible Environment you’re billed [for resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances).

So in the former case you’d have to determine the amount of RAM memory you believe fits your needs while on the latter you can see more clearly the effect on your project’s billing of the amount of dependency libraries you have installed for your app.

Comment: I see in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime we have r/w access to /tmp. The note suggesting MYSQL for persistent data. I assume this is because the vm will be re-launched for scalability. So, the most straightforward way to r/w a file is in a bucket; which requires the cloud storage apis. I install composer on my local host. I test the app in the local environment which will write to the cloud bucket? I see now that scaling the app, a new instance, will create collisions trying to access the same file?

Comment: Refer to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features to understand the differences between Standard and Flexible environment when it comes to local disk access.

Comment: You you can also use Cloud Datastore as explained in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-datastore.  To more background on storage mechanisms choices please refer to https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/.